# Wordpress Database Fatal Error

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm receiving this error when trying to run a PHP script against my WordPress database:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class wpdb
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

---

#### Edit

Code:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../wp-config.php'); 
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../wp-includes/wp-db.php'); 
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
$dupes = $wpdb->get_results('select bad_rows.* from wp_posts as bad_rows inner join ( select post_title, MIN(id) as min_id from wp_posts group by post_title having count(*) > 1 ) as good_rows on good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title and good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id; '); 

foreach ($dupes as $dupe) 
{ 
  echo $dupe->post_title ."\n"; 
}

$wpdb->query(' delete bad_rows.* from wp_posts as bad_rows inner join ( select post_title, MIN(id) as min_id from wp_posts group by post_title having count(*) > 1 ) as good_rows on good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title and good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id; ');
```

Comment: I added the code you left in response to one of the answers. I tried to format it as best I could but some things may have been lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the corrupted `functions.php` file in the `wp-includes` folder with a new functions.php file from a new install of wordpress. Make sure you get one from the same version of wordpress. Not sure if a different version will get the same results.

This fixed my issue of the `Call to undefined function require_wp_db() /filename/filename/...wp-settings.php on line 71`, and I was able to login.

I suggest to back up your `functions.php` file before installing anything like sidebars. That's what caused my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be including the Wordpress bootstrap twice. Eliminate the second call or use [require_once()](https://www.php.net/require_once).

How does your PHP script look like?

Comment: <?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../wp-config.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
 
$wpdb->show_errors();
 
$dupes = $wpdb->get_results('select bad_rows.*
from wp_posts as bad_rows
inner join (
select post_title, MIN(id) as min_id
from wp_posts
group by post_title
having count(*) > 1
) as good_rows on good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title
and good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id;
');
 
foreach ($dupes as $dupe) {
echo $dupe->post_title ."\n";
}

Comment: $wpdb->query('
delete bad_rows.*
from wp_posts as bad_rows
inner join (
select post_title, MIN(id) as min_id
from wp_posts
group by post_title
having count(*) > 1
) as good_rows on good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title
and good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id;
');
?>

Answer (score 0):

I can only go by my own Wordpress install, but;

wp-config.php;

```
[line 30] require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

wp-settings.php;

```
[line 242] require_wp_db();
```

wp-includes/functions.php

```
[line 2534] function require_wp_db() {
                global $wpdb;
                if ( file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' ) )
                    require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' );
                else
                    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/wp-db.php' );
            }
```

Although you (and the require_wp_db function) use require_once, it seems as though your call to wp-includes/wp-db.php is unnecessary. Try commenting it out and see if the problem disappears. If not, follow the trail down into wp-config.php, commenting out includes as you go. Hopefully you'll be able to isolate the line that is causing the issue...

Answer (score 0):

check your file is calling properly then make $wpdb variable as a global variable(global $wpdb;)

```
 include_once( __DIR__. '/../../../../wp-config.php');
    include_once( __DIR__. '/../../../../wp-load.php');
    include_once( __DIR__. '/../../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
    class Myclass{
     function anyname(){
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table", OBJECT );
        print_r($results) ;
     }
```